# Install Pageturner within Plone 4.1

Tags: pdf, plone, add-on

We have updated our Plone sites to version 4.1

We would like to install also the Pageturner PDF viewer in the site to give our users more functionality on medical articles which are published as PDFs.

We added in the buildout file two parts:

```
eggs = 
     .......
     wc.pageturner

zcml = 
     .......
     wc.pageturner
```

We also installed on our Ubntu server machine the swftools with the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install swftools
```

Running buildout is going well without any errors. 
After starting the zinstance the Plone sites are not available within the browser.

If you are interested we could write some functional documentation to add on plone.org with the product.

What can I do? where is the error? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to provide more information here. What do you see when you run the zope instance in the foreground with "bin/instance fg"?

Comment: Just made new release to fix this. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wc.pageturner/1.2.4

Answer (score 1):

It seems a common problem relative to the way permissions are handled in Plone 4.1.

Just add the following:

```
<include package="Products.CMFCore" file="permissions.zcml"
    xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml"
    zcml:condition="have plone-41"
    />
```

in every configure.zcml file where CMF permissions (cmf.ManagePortal, cmf.ModifyPortalContent, etc.) are mentioned.